# "Splitting" an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Feature request:  It would be nice if some time in the future we could accept multiple answers per question.  (You don't need to read the rest)

---

Recently I asked a question about converting temperature output to Celsius within my conky setup [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/226994/37700).  What I didn't know was that there were two ways to do it - one with a native Conky option and another with bash.  They were both great, prompt answers, and most importantly **were equally valid**.

What would be really nice is if (far in the future) one could split the reputation between two or more answers.  I know that the reputation isn't that important and an upvote is almost as much rep anyway, but I wouldn't want anybody to think that there is only one way to do it (that only one of the answers is valid).

Comment: Some of this has been covered in http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5421/19490 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13396/163868. To split reputation you can use a bounty.

Comment: All right.  It looks like [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13397) from one of those questions has a good approach - accept the one that you actually use and upvote the others.

Comment: If you can't decide on two good answers, you could always let the community influence your decision by going off which of the two (or more) excellent answers got the most votes and selecting that as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a best answer for the asker.
And for other good answers which are not the chosen ones there is the upvote.

Comment: What I'm talking about is when there two answers of equal merit (when there *isn't* a best answer for the asker).

Comment: Then you have to make a desission. There will always be equal merit answers because here are many wise guys around. Thats how Stack Exchange works. :)